# Modified Entity Workspace is ignored when generating SQL

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, dbcontext

I have an Entity Model (EDMX) file and EF 4.3.1.  I am trying to make a run-time modification to the EDMX (change the `store:Schema` of the tables/entitySets used in generating the query).  I am using code based on the [EF Model Adapter](http://efmodeladapter.codeplex.com/) project by B. Haynes.

It appears that I can make the changes to the XML just fine using the schema model adapter, and load it into a metadata workspace and then pass it to the connection.  However, when the query is generated by the DbContext/EF framework code, it uses the old value for the schema.

1. Create a new MyEntities
2. Load the EDMX medata data manually
3. Replace the "store:Schema" value with the new desired value
4. Create the metadata workspace from the modified XML
5. Return a new EntityConnection using that modified workspace
6. Query the data (`from x in db.Table select x`)

This is the basics of what is going on.  We create our dbContext by creating a new EntityConnection based on the modified workspace and the connection.  There is also some provider wrapping and such going on, for logging, etc.  Sorry if that's confusing.

```
public MyEntities(): base( this.Create("name=MyEntitiesConnStr"), true)
{
}

public static DbConnection Create(string connectionString)
{
    var ecsb = ConnectionHelper.ResolveConnectionStringDetails(connectionString);
    var workspace = GetModifiedEntityWorkspace(ecsb);
    var storeConnection = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(ecsb.Provider).CreateConnection();
    Debug.Assert(storeConnection != null, "storeConnection != null");
    storeConnection.ConnectionString = ecsb.ProviderConnectionString;
    var wrappedConnection = MyWrappedConnetion.WrapConnection(storeConnection);
    _log.Debug("Creating new entity connection");
    var newEntityConnection = new EntityConnection(workspace, wrappedConnection);
    WireEvents(wrappedConnection);
    return newEntityConnection;
}

private static MetadataWorkspace GetModifiedEntityWorkspace(EntityConnectionStringBuilder ecsb)
{
    // instantiate manager class
    // read all XML items from the embedded resources
    // change the store:schema to the real one for this environment
    // <EntitySet Name="..." store:Type="Tables" store:Schema="SCM" store:Name="TBLX">
    // create new MetadataWorksspace(ssdl,cdl,...)
}
```

Any idea where/why it is still getting the old `Schema` value for the query?  I think it worked right with EF 4.0,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with the `<DefiningQuery>` element under the entity set.

This element contains a definition of the base query used to define the entity.  Perhaps something changed and now they refer to that for speed reasons.  It is necessary to modify that query as well, and then the schema change will take effect.

```
<EntitySet Name="MYTABLE" store:Type="Tables" store:Schema="MYSCHEMA" ...>
<DefiningQuery>
    SELECT MYTABLE.COLUMN [...REPEAT..]
    FROM MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE AS MYTABLE
</definingQuery>
```

So, changing `"MYSCHEMA"` in both those locations fixes it.  Just the `store:Schema` element is not enough.